# If $a,b >0$ and $a+b \sqrt{d} = \left(\alpha+\beta \sqrt{d} \right)^k$ with $k>1$ then $|\alpha|<a$ and $0<|\beta|<b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to show that if $d$ is a positive, squarefree integer with $d \not \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} 4)$ and $a,b, \alpha, \beta$ are integers with $a,b >0 $ and such that $a+b\sqrt{d}$ and $\alpha+\beta\sqrt{d}$ are units in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and satisfy
$$a+b \sqrt{d} = \left(\alpha+\beta \sqrt{d} \right)^k$$
for some integer $k>1$, then $|\alpha|<a$ and $0<|\beta|<b$.

I have no idea from where to start, I've shown that it is true for $k=2$ looking for an inductive proof, buy I got stuck really fast so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $a+b\sqrt d>1$. It follows that $|\alpha+\beta\sqrt{d}|>1$ also. Therefore $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same sign. If that sign is negative, then $k$ must be even, and we might as well replace $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with their negatives. So without loss of generality $\alpha>0,\beta>0$.

Write $u=\alpha+\beta\sqrt d$, $v=\alpha-\beta\sqrt d$. We know that $v=\pm 1/u$, but either sign is possible. Anyway $|v|<1$. By conjugation we see that $v^k=a-b\sqrt{d}$. Therefore
$$
2a=u^k+v^k>u^k-1,\qquad 2\alpha=u+v\le u+1.
$$
But $u\ge1+\sqrt2$ (with equality possible when $d=2$), so elementary tools give the inequality $u^k\ge u^2>u+2$. This implies
$$
2a>u^k-1>u+1\ge 2\alpha.
$$
I suspect that the claim $b>\beta$ can be proven with a similar method. $2b\sqrt d=u^k-v^k$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have a couple of questions. I don't get at the beggining why $\alpha, \beta$ have the same sign, and why cannot one of them be $0$. Later, why is $v^k = a- b \sqrt{d}$, shouldn't we have also a $\pm$ sign? And later, assuming all is true, for $b$ the same inequalities would hold, I mean as $|v|<1$ we have that $u^k -v^k >u^k-1$ and $u-v < u+1$, isn't it?

Comment: @Eparoh Because $\alpha+\beta\sqrt{d}$ is a unit, its norm must be $\pm1$. So
$$|\alpha+\beta\sqrt d|\cdot |\alpha-\beta\sqrt d|=1,$$ as the norm is the product of the conjugates.Conjugation:
$$\sigma: q_+q_2\sqrt{d}\mapsto q_1-q_2\sqrt{d}$$ is a homomorphism (a field automorphism). Therefore
$$\sigma(u^k)=\sigma(u)^k=v^k.$$

Comment: And. Correct, that argument seems to work for the purposes of comparing $b$ and $|\beta|$.

Comment: Now I see it, I didn't think about conjugation in terms of homomorphisms, but I still can't see why $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must have same signs.

Comment: @Eparoh One of  $|\alpha+\beta\sqrt{d}|$ and $|\alpha-\beta\sqrt{d}|$ is $>1$ and the other $<1$. Surely the one with same signs is the larger.

Comment: Thank you! All clear now.